# Switch workspaces in VSCode without re-loading every time

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on a project involving code from a number of different repositories. I have a workspace for each. I'd like to be able to quickly switch between them. I've found two ways to do this:

1. Use `workbench.action.openRecent`, but loading a new workspace takes some time.
2. Create a window for each workspace and cycle between them. Normally this would be fine, but all the workspaces are remote, I can only access them via VPN, and (strangely but unavoidably) I need to connect and disconnect from the VPN multiple times a day. Every time I do that, I need to re-open / re-load all the windows. Not a huge deal, but after a while it gets tedious.

Is there any way to quickly switch workspaces without creating a new window for each?

Comment: No, "the obvious solution" is to simply open three different instances of MVSCode.  I have no idea why you consider two extra windows "clutter".  Especially since you can easily minimize or overlap them at will :(  Geez...

Comment: I clarified the original post. That's fine if there's no alternative, I was just checking.

Comment: Did you try vscode extensions like vscode-workspace-switcher?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Workspace Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomsaunders.vscode-workspace-explorer) to switch easily between your workspaces.